# Android - Voice recognition instead of speech

Tags: java, android, android-intent, voice-recognition, voice-recording

I am researching Voice Recognition on Android for a school project. I am having trouble finding information because a lot of questions use voice and speech recognition interchangeably.

What I want the app to be able to do is be able to distinguish between one person speaking or another (Was that John or Jill speaking). Looking through developer docs I came across `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` and `SpeechRecognizer` and am wondering if these have the functionality that I am looking for. The RecognizerIntent doc mention speech so I am unsure. This app I found on github seems to be using it for my purpose.

[Github Link](https://github.com/mumumu/Titanium-Android-VoiceRecognition/blob/master/src/org/mumumu/ti/android/speech/VoiceRecognitionProxy.java)

Is what I am looking to do built into Android? I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the web for "android speaker recognition".

When I tried this, quite a few interesting links showed up, but there was just one app on the first result page: [SpeakerVerify](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.speakerverify%26hl%3Den&ei=mfHKVKORHdOxogStp4KADA&usg=AFQjCNGUjKatskzLtOuPk3hM0PdRJkuxQA&sig2=JlnSaCe1NNqLGX-GI1-Ztw). It is actually an educational tool, so it might be perfect for your needs.